# Pivoting data into JSON with numbered fields

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2017, I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
Code VARCHAR (2)
, RegionCode VARCHAR (10)
, Prop INT
, Val VARCHAR (200)
, PropF VARCHAR (50)
, PropFD VARCHAR (200)
)

INSERT INTO #Data
(
    Code, RegionCode, Prop, Val, PropF, PropFD
)
VALUES
    ('AD', 'DLSO324', 1, 'Abcdefg', 'SD', 'SomeDescription')
  , ('AD', 'DLSO324', 2, 'sdfadf', 'SA', 'SomethingA')
  , ('AD', 'DLSO324', 3, 'gfdsdfg', 'SB', 'SomethingB')
  , ('AD', 'DLSO324', 4, 'r43df', 'SC', 'SomethingC')
  , ('AD', 'DLSO324', 5, 'GHD-123', 'SD2', 'SomethingD')
  , ('AD', 'DLSO324', 6, '2013-03-42', 'SE', 'SomethingE')
  , ('AD', 'XR1046', 34, 'Value1', 'dsf', 'Desc1')
  , ('AD', 'XR1046', 65, 'Value1', 'gfsd', 'Desc1')
  , ('AD', 'XR1046', 23, 'Value1', 'dg', 'Desc1')
  , ('AD', 'XR1046', 67, 'Value1', 'fgh', 'Desc1')
  , ('AD', 'XR1046', 45, 'Value1', 'fh', 'Desc1')
  , ('AD', 'XR1046', 99, 'Value1', 'hfgfgh', 'Desc1')

SELECT  *
FROM    #Data
```

where you'll notice that a code and region code has multiple props with each prop having a value (val), a property code (propF), and a property field description (PropFD). The number of properties a Code and RegionCode combination can have varies from anywhere between 1 and 100 and different combinations of Code and RegionCode can have different PropF and PropFD values even if they share the same prop number.

What I need to do is write a query that pivots the data and produces one row per Code and RegionCode with some JSON data. I need to completely flatten out the JSON so that each Prop number has its own Val, PropF, and PropFD field.  My desired structure is as follow (you'll notice that the _number corresponds to the prop value in the #Data table):

```
[
  {
    "Val_1": "Abcdefg",
    "PropF_1": "SD",
    "PropFD_1": "SomeDescription",
    "Val_2": "sdfadf",
    "PropF_2": "SA",
    "PropFD_2": "SomethingA",
    "Val_3": "gfdsdfg",
    "PropF_3": "SB",
    "PropFD_3": "SomethingB",
    "Val_4": "r43df",
    "PropF_4": "SC",
    "PropFD_4": "SomethingC",
    "Val_5": "GHD-123",
    "PropF_5": "SD2",
    "PropFD_5": "SomethingD",
    "Val_6": "2013-03-42",
    "PropF_6": "SE",
    "PropFD_6": "SomethingE"
  }
]
```

So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT      x.Code
          , x.RegionCode
          , (   SELECT  y.Prop id
                      , y.Val
                      , y.PropF
                      , y.PropFD
                FROM    #Data y
                WHERE   y.Code = x.Code
                        AND y.RegionCode = x.RegionCode
                FOR JSON PATH) FieldData
FROM        #Data x
GROUP BY    x.Code
          , x.RegionCode
```

Is there a way for me to get my desired structure using JOINs and the SQL Server 2017 JSON functions? I want to avoid using PIVOT if possible due to performance reasons.

Comment: What performance reasons? Use the right tool for the job and if later it performs badly sort it them. Pre-empting SQL performance issues isn't generally a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SQL Server is declarative by design, your desired results would require either Dynamic SQL or some String Manipulation.

The following demonstrates a little string manipulation in concert with  `string_agg()`

**Example**

```
SELECT  Code
       ,RegionCode
       ,FieldData  = '[{'+string_agg(concat('"Val_',prop,'":"',Val,'","PropF_',Prop,'":"',PropF,'","PropFD_',Prop,'":"',PropFD,'"'),',')+'}]'
FROM    #Data
Group  By Code,RegionCode
```

**Results**

[image]

**Results First Record's JSON**

```
[
  {
    "Val_1": "Abcdefg",
    "PropF_1": "SD",
    "PropFD_1": "SomeDescription",
    "Val_2": "sdfadf",
    "PropF_2": "SA",
    "PropFD_2": "SomethingA",
    "Val_3": "gfdsdfg",
    "PropF_3": "SB",
    "PropFD_3": "SomethingB",
    "Val_4": "r43df",
    "PropF_4": "SC",
    "PropFD_4": "SomethingC",
    "Val_5": "GHD-123",
    "PropF_5": "SD2",
    "PropFD_5": "SomethingD",
    "Val_6": "2013-03-42",
    "PropF_6": "SE",
    "PropFD_6": "SomethingE"
  }
]
```

**The Second Record's JSON**

```
[
  {
    "Val_34": "Value1",
    "PropF_34": "dsf",
    "PropFD_34": "Desc1",
    "Val_65": "Value1",
    "PropF_65": "gfsd",
    "PropFD_65": "Desc1",
    "Val_23": "Value1",
    "PropF_23": "dg",
    "PropFD_23": "Desc1",
    "Val_67": "Value1",
    "PropF_67": "fgh",
    "PropFD_67": "Desc1",
    "Val_45": "Value1",
    "PropF_45": "fh",
    "PropFD_45": "Desc1",
    "Val_99": "Value1",
    "PropF_99": "hfgfgh",
    "PropFD_99": "Desc1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Woody Always happy to help